# WKWebView content

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView().The size of my webView height = 100.
I am loading a .gif image inside WKWebview. The size of gif image height = 300. I want to compress the image inside webview to fit inside it.

AS shown in below screen shot, the image is not shrinking to webView Size,its original size is 300
[image]

If i give sixe of WkWebview to 300 , it comes proper
[image].

I have tried giving

```
    self.webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.webView.sizeToFit()
    self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = true

    self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
    self.webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

This is the way I am adding the WKWebview:

```
self.webView = WKWebView() 
self.webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 64, width: self.view.frame.width, height:200) 
self.webView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth 
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
self.view.addSubview(self.webView) 
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"token", ofType: "gif")
let gifData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!) 
self.webView.load(gifData as! Data, mimeType: "image/gif", characterEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the configuration of your web view, you can either:

1. style the `img` tag so that it fills the height of the web view:

   ```
   let htmlContent = "<img src=\"token.gif\" style=\"margin: auto; height: 100%\" />"
   ```
2. or hardcode it's height:

   ```
   let htmlContent = <img src=\"token.gif\" style=\"margin: auto; height: 300px\" />"
   ```

   alternatively, you can use a string interpolated constant instead of the hardcoded value

   ```
   let htmlContent = "<img src=\"token.gif\" style=\"margin: auto; height: \(webViewHeight)px\" />"
   ```

You can then load the html to the web view:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

To speed up the web view, you can inline the image data instead of referencing the gif file - see [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) for more on this topic.

Comment: This is the way i am adding WkWebview:                                       self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 64, width:    self.view.frame.width, height:200)                                             
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth   
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)

Comment: self.view.addSubview(self.webView)                                                                       
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"token", ofType: "gif")
        let gifData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        self.webView.load(gifData as! Data, mimeType: "image/gif", characterEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL() as URL)

Comment: All i need is to resize the image loaded inside the WKWebview to webview size. @Cristik

Comment: I tried your solution. "webView.loadHTMLString" not loading anything.

Comment: Adding base url worked ! Thanks for the quick fix. Only thing is webview takes some miliseconds to load the content once view is loaded.

Comment: Is there any other component in iOS which can load gif image except webview ?

Comment: I tried doing it, but as per stack overflow policy , for beginners its not allowing to show publicly the upvote though taken into account

Comment: using `height: 100%` works much better.